# Отрицательный margin у контейнера

Tags: css, вёрстка

Никак не могу добиться того, чтобы первая строка (класс "row") имела отрицательный margin сверху. Каким образом это можно сделать если не использовать свойство "position" и не менять стили класса "col"?

```css
.color1 {
        background-color: #2e6da4;
    }

    .color2 {
        background-color: #6989a0;
    }

    .color3 {
        background-color: #aad9a0;
    }

    ._row {
        margin-top: -15px;
    }

    ._row:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

    ._col {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="color3">
    ...
</div>
<div class="_row color1">
    <div class="_col">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="_col">
        2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="_row color2">
    <div class="_col">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="_col">
        4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="color3">
    ...
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы получился следующий результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Введи модификатор для первой строки, например `._row--thin`.

```css
.color1 {
  background-color: #2e6da4;
}

.color2 {
  background-color: #6989a0;
}

.color3 {
  background-color: #aad9a0;
}


/*._row {
        margin-top: -15px;
 } */

/*Модификатор*/
._row--thin ._col {
  margin-top: 0;
}

._row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

._col {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="color3">
  ...
</div>

<div class="_row _row--thin color1">
  <div class="_col">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="_col">
    2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="_row color2">
  <div class="_col">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="_col">
    4
  </div>
</div>

<div class="color3">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: не подходит, в условии сказано, что изменять стили ._col нельзя